# SSH Google Compute Engine down?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

There's an issue with SSH access today ? Don't know why I can't access to my instances today, from a MobaXterm or the SSH webinterface in Google Cloud (impossible to connect port 22). 
From Google Cloud Shell => ssh: connect to host XXXX port 22: Connection timed out

Global issue or only my account ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to try the following and check if you are able to connect:

1. Can you able to ping or SSH into VM instance using gcloud [command](http://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) ?
2. Could you also try running cloud shell in [safe mode](http://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#safe_mode).
3. If you are still running the issue after trying 2 methods, please try to restart the cloud shell (This can be done by selecting restart option from hamburger menu on top right of your Cloud shell) and see if that fixes.
4. You can [interact with the serial console](http://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) so you can more easily troubleshoot instances that are not booting properly or that are otherwise inaccessible.

Please let me know of the results.

Comment: My bad,
We are using an other server to access to the one I mentioned previously and with a restart of this server now the SSH access is good again.